# How do I structure an ear file in JBoss AS 7 to avoid class cast exception?

Tags: jboss7.x, ear

Currently we are using JBoss AS 5 and using single ear file with the deployment structure as follows

```
company.ear
      |_ webapp1.war
      |_ webapp2.war
      |_ lib
      |    |_ ejb1.jar
      |    |_ ejb2.jar
      |_ META-INF
      |    |_application.xml
      |_ thirdparty1.jar
      |_ thirdparty2.jar
```

All ejb which are common to web application are kept in lib and thirdparty jars are kept in ear root path. This is working fine.

Now, we are migrating the same to JBoss 7.1.1. and we have tried with following deployment structures.

```
1. company.ear
      |_ webapp1.war
      |_ webapp2.war
      |_ lib
      |    |_ thirdparty1.jar
      |    |_ thirdparty2.jar
      |_ META-INF
      |    |_application.xml
      |    |_jboss-deployment-structure.xml
      |_ ejb1.jar
      |_ ejb2.jar

2. company.ear
      |_ webapp1.war
      |_ webapp2.war
      |_ lib
      |    |_ ejb1.jar
      |    |_ ejb2.jar
      |_ META-INF
          |_application.xml
          |_jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

In the second deployment structure, we have defined thirdparty jars in modules folder and added global dependency in the `stanalone.xml`.

Though we are following JBoss AS 7 migration document and some work-around, we are getting ClassCastExceptions during deployment.

how do I keep from getting these exceptions in my deployment file?

Or how can we force JBoss SA to load all EJB jars by a single class loader.

Comment: Check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).